# Encode # sign in url

Tags: c#

I have a URL in a `string` that i want to encode, which looks like this:

```
"/Some/Url/To/A/File/Attachment#image.gif"
```

I want to encode this string so that the `#` is encoded, but the `/` should remain as they are. So I can't use `HttpUtility.UrlEncode`, and `HttpUtility.HttpEncode` won't work either because that doesn't encode the `#` sign.

Is there a way to encode this character and possible other characters as well? Perhaps there's a way to use `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` and tell it not to encode `/` (slashes)?

Any ideas?

Comment: before encode and decode why cant u try ascii code for #.so that it will not affect much..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to deal with the #, you can simply replace it:

```
    string url = "/Some/Url/To/A/File/Attachment#image.gif";
    Console.WriteLine(url.Replace("#", HttpUtility.UrlEncode("#")));
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably have to do it by hand. Regex find and replace might be a good choice.

```
var str = "/Some/Url/To/A/File/Attachment#image.gif";
var str2 = Regex.Replace(str, "#", "%23");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest solution, in your case, would be this:

```
string encodedString = originalString.Replace("#", "%23");
```

References:

http://www.degraeve.com/reference/urlencoding.php

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx